# Converting calendar to date in dd-MMM-yyyy format

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am trying to add 17 days to `10-APR-2014` and convert the date to `dd-MMM-yyy`y format, but I am getting `Sun Apr 27 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2014`.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
public class HelloWorld{

    public static void main(String []args){
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(new Date());
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 17);
        String output = sdf.format(c.getTime());
        System.out.println(output);
        System.out.print(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").parse(output));
    }
}
```

How can I make the output be `27-Apr-2014`?

Comment: I want to store the output in date object not string object

Comment: A date does not have a format.

Comment: what is the mistake? I am unable to understand. I have to add a few days too.

Comment: `please help me bring the output 27-Apr-2014 in date not string` Is impossible. You need to use a `SimpleDateFormat` to `format` the date into a `String` with that format.

Comment: If it is impossible, how do I add days to a date and then convert it to a date again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51025/discussion-between-freakyuser-and-sotirios-delimanolis)

Comment: What are you doing here: `c.add(Calendar.DATE, 17);`?

Comment: I have added 17 days to the current date.

Answer (score 3):

You are printing a Date parsed from a String formatted from the calendar date.

Instead, print the formatted calendar date:

```
System.out.print(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format(c.getTime()));
```

---

If displaying and using the dates is disjunct, do this:

```
Date date; // from Calendar or wherever
String str = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format(date));
// display str
```

Then when you want to do something with a selected date:

```
String selection;
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").parse(selection));
// do something with date
```

Comment: This gives me a string output but I want a date object. When I parse the above string I am unable to get it in my format. Btw, I am not going to print in Sysout, I am going to store it in a hashmap.

Comment: Dates do not have a format. They are an instant in time *only*. You need to display Strings; format the Date at rendering time as per my code.

Comment: I need this date because in the end I have to compare this date to another. I won't be able to this with a string, will I?

Comment: You can compare Strings as if they were dates by converting them to dates! Use `SimpleDateFormat.parse()` to convert a String into Date.

Comment: Hey come on, that is my question, I am unable to convert the resulting string

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by Bohemian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23172298/642706) is correct. Here I present an alternative solution.

## Avoid j.u.Date

The java.util.Date and .Calendar classes bundled with Java are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them. Use either [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or the new java.time package in Java 8.

## Date-Only

If you need only a date, without any time component, both [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) and [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) offer a [LocalDate](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) class.

## Time Zone

Even for a date-only, you still need a time zone to get "today". At any moment the date may vary ±1 depending on your location on the globe. If you do not specify a time zone, the JVM's default time zone will be applied.

## Example Code

Here is some example code in Joda-Time 2.3.

Determine "today" based on some time zone. Add seventeen days.

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" );
LocalDate today = new LocalDate( timeZone );
LocalDate seventeenDaysLater = today.plusDays( 17 );
```

Generate a String representation of the date-time value…

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "dd-MMM-yyyy" );
String output = formatter.print( seventeenDaysLater );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "today: " + today );
System.out.println( "seventeenDaysLater: " + seventeenDaysLater );
System.out.println( "output: " + output );
```

When run…

```
today: 2014-04-21
seventeenDaysLater: 2014-05-08
output: 08-May-2014
```