# Comparing different format dates in javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have got date objects in jsp. One is coming from java page and the other one is coming from the same jsp.
The formats of the dates are:

```
Wed May 07 00:00:14 CDT 2014  
07-May-2014
```

Now how do I compare these two dates, please help. I don't know how to convert these in javascript to the same format.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Is this a Javascript question or a Java question? I can show you how to compare them in Java but that won't help you with your Javascript.

Comment: I have to compare the dates, I am unable to do it. The end result is to be seen in javascript. So, I want to compare it in javascript.

Comment: So what does this question have to do with Java again?

Comment: A part of the question involves java because I am retrieving the first date from java.

Comment: Fine, let us consider that the question is completely javascript, now is there a way to compare these 2 dates?

Comment: What is a Java page? How are you retrieving the date?

Comment: Please refer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23172229/converting-calendar-to-date-in-dd-mmm-yyyy-format)

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just export the Date in Java in the same format that JavaScript uses?

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("DD-MMM-YYYY");
```

or

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM DD HH:mm:ss z YYY");
```

That way they are easier to compare using:

```
var n = date1.localeCompare(date2);
```

Comment: I am unable to bring the first date in the same format. See my [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23172229/converting-calendar-to-date-in-dd-mmm-yyyy-format)